# Phonejs Layout Change

Tags: javascript, phonejs

Can anyone explain to me how a layout change would be forced on a phonehjs navigate. For instance I have a project that uses the Navigation Type: "navbar" but for some reason navigation that occurs from within the app but outside the nav buttons (i.e. a list menu item) causes the Layout to change to the simple layout which does not contain the nav icons. Once these icons are lost, they are permanently lost as the layout never changes back to "navbar"?

Comment: Could you provide an example? Actually, you can specify the layout for each of your views. The app navigation type in app.config is default layout that is used, when view layout is not specified. Maybe the view where you loose navigation has specified layout (not navbar)? You can find detailed description here http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Framework_Markup_Components/dxView/Configuration?version=13_2#layout